# Spring Boot and HTML Required request parameter 'Coord1' for method parameter type String is not present]

Tags: java, python, html, spring, spring-boot

I have just began to work with Html + springboot. I have prepared two files
the HTML file with a form as bellow

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <title>Add Info</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/style.css}"/>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Insert an Info:</h1>
       
      <!--  
         In Thymeleaf the equivalent of
         JSP's ${pageContext.request.contextPath}/edit.html
         would be @{/edit.html}         
         -->
      <form th:action="@{}" method="post">
        <input type="text" th:name="Coord1"/> </br>
        <input type="text" th:name="Coord2"/> </br>
        <input type="text" th:name="Coord3"/> </br>
        <input type="text" th:name="Coord4"/> </br>
        <input type="submit"/> 
        </form>
       
      <br/>
       
      <!-- Check if errorMessage is not null and not empty -->
       
      <div th:if="${errorMessage}" th:utext="${errorMessage}"
         style="color:red;font-style:italic;">
         ...
      </div>
       
   </body>
</html>
```

I want to get the four values coord1 coord2, coord3 and coord4. My java controller file contains the lines

```
package com.example.project.controller;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class MainController {
 @RequestMapping(value="",method=RequestMethod.GET)
 public void addAObjectForm(@RequestParam("Coord1") String Coord1,@RequestParam("Coord2") String Coord2,@RequestParam("Coord3") String Coord3, @RequestParam("Coord4")String Coord4) throws IOException {
     System.out.println(Coord1);
 }
}I
```

When I run this code I get the error

> [2m2021-07-12 22:28:57.206[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m18812[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-3][0;39m [36m.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required request parameter 'Coord1' for method parameter type String is not present]

Could anyone help me please

Comment: _Request parameters_ come in the query string, which is what you get with `action="GET"`. You're using `action="POST"`.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I have changed post to get but still the some exeption. Looks like it can see the Html file or something like that

Answer (score 0):

you use POST action in your form, and u use GET method in your controller. match those things and update status please :)

Comment: I have modified the code but always the some error

Comment: how about change input HTML code also?  <input type="text" th:name="Coord1"/>  -> <input type="text" th:name="Coord1" name="Coord1"/>  add just "name" attribute too

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly add thymeleaf dependency in your pom.xml.
2. Give some action inside the:action like

   `<form th:action="@{detail}" method="post">`
3. Use make controller like

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

  @GetMapping("/")
  public String show() {
      return "show"; // I had given name to view part as show.html
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/detail", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public void addAObjectForm(@RequestParam(value = "Coord1", required = false) String Coord1,
                             @RequestParam(value = "Coord2", required = false) String Coord2,
                             @RequestParam(value = "Coord3", required = false) String Coord3,
                             @RequestParam(value = "Coord4", required = false) String Coord4) throws IOException {
      System.out.println(Coord1);
  }
}
```